# preg_match not working with single quotes

Tags: string, validation, namespaces, preg-match, stripslashes

i'm having a problem to escape the single quotes on the preg_match function.

I want to make a function that matches all kinds of names, also the likes of O'Neill etc.

```
   if(preg_match("/^(\w){1,12}\s(\w){2,15}\D$/", stripslashes($name)))
    {
        $name = $db->real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Name format should be: first name + second name(i.e. John Smith)      
   </br>';
    }
```

I've tried absolutely everything and also looked and various examples from the board, nothing helped; i've tried:

```
(\w'-)
(A-Za-z'-)
(A-Za-z\'\)
```

Ideally the function should allow a combination of first + second name (not allowing any integers).

Regards
Jacek

Answer (score 0):

Ranges are indicated with `[]`, not `()`.

Either of your suggestion would work with the correct brackets:

```
[\w'-]
[A-Za-z'-]
```